# Programming an autoupdater / launcher application in c# that works with any program

Tags: c#

I am making a program updater / launcher that can be used for any program.
I have a config file on the client and a config file on a http server. I get version numbers from both of them and compare them and if they are are not = then update the client.

I have everything working except for when the update starts. What I need is say if someone downloaded my application and do not use if for say a month and in between that time I have 5 or so updates.
The problem is how to I get my program to download the first update , install it and then download the next update untill they have all been downloaded?

I am new to programming and this is the only kind of app I can think of to work on to learn.
Thanks

My settings.conf on http server XML File.

```
<Table>
<Product>
<Product_id>1</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.1</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.1.exe</Product_Url>
<Product_id>2</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.2</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.2.exe</Product_Url>

<Product_id>3</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.3</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.3.exe</Product_Url>

<Product_id>4</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.4</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.4.exe</Product_Url>

<Product_id>5</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.5</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.5.exe</Product_Url>


</Product>
</Table>
```

My Client Config XML file.

```
<Table>
<Product>
<Product_id>1</Product_id>
<Product_name>Infected</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.0</Product_version>
<Product_Url>http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.1.exe</Product_Url>
</Product>
</Table>
```

My C# Form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

namespace Launcher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string localversion { get; set; }
        public string remoteversion { get; set; }
        public string UpdateURL { get; set; }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.kceoc.com/");
            webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.kceoc.com/");

            button1.Enabled = false;    // Disable the launch button untill all updates are completed.
            GetLocalXMLFile();          //Run first xml function to start everything off.


        }

        private void GetLocalXMLFile()
        {
            try     //Start error checking.
            {
                using (XmlTextReader localxml = new XmlTextReader("settings.conf"))  //Load xml file in same folder as launcher.exe
                {
                    while (localxml.Read())  // Start reading the settings.conf file
                    {
                        switch (localxml.NodeType) //Get the Node that we will use.
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                label1.Text = localxml.Value;  //Change the text of label1 to value of Node.
                                string localversion = localxml.Value;  // Store Node Value in string localversion for latter use.
                                GetRemoteXMLFile(localversion, remoteversion); //Everything went ok and got a value from Node so pass this all to our next function witch is get remote xml.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                label1.Text = "Local Config not found. Reinstall the application"; // Catch error incase file is not there.
            }
        }

        private void GetRemoteXMLFile(string localversion, string remoteversion)
        {
            try  //Start error checking
            {
                using (XmlTextReader remotexml = new XmlTextReader("http://localhost/update/settings.conf"))  //Load up remote xml on web server
                {
                    while (remotexml.Read())  //Start reading xml file from server.
                    {
                        switch (remotexml.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                label2.Text = remotexml.Value; // Change value of label2 to remote xml node value
                                remoteversion = remotexml.Value; // Set the remoteversion string to remotexml.value
                                CompareXMLFileVersions(localversion, remoteversion); // Everything went ok so send localversion string and remoteversion string to compare function.
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                label1.Text = "Remote config not found. Maby website id down?"; // Catch error incase file is not there.
            }
        }


        private void CompareXMLFileVersions(string localversion, string remoteversion)
        {

            label1.Text = localversion;         // Just so we can see the value in the lables to konw if they have value or not.
            label2.Text = remoteversion;         // Just so we can see the value in the lables to konw if they have value or not.

            if (localversion == remoteversion)  // Comparing the values of localversion and remoteversion and if they have same value then
            {                                   // change label3 to You have latest version.
                label3.Text = "You have the latest version";

            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "There is a new version. Starting update process here"; // If localversion and remoteversion are diffrent then let user know the files are out of date and start the updating process..
                GetListOfUpdates(remoteversion);  // Starting the updating process function..     

            }
        }

        private void GetListOfUpdates(string remoteversion)
        {

            //WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            //webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            //webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            //webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(remoteversion), @"v1.0.0.1.exe");

            string url = "http://localhost/update/v1.0.0.1.exe";
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            downloader.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadFileCompleted);
            downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadProgressChanged);
            downloader.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "temp.exe");



        }


        void downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
        void downloader_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.Error != null)
            //    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            //else
            //    MessageBox.Show("Completed!!!");
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The main problem I am having is with GetListOfUpdates. I have a list of updates in my xml file and what I would like is for the program to go through the list and download and install one after the other so that way if someone waited a month or so to update they can still get all the updates instead of just getting the 1.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

> I am new to programming and this is the only kind of app I can think of to work on to learn. Thanks

Depending on *how* new you are, I'd really recommend you start with something a little easier. Otherwise, the first thing I'd recommend you do is to actually draw a flowchart. Your logic looks a little off, and it looks as if you're huffing it trying to design this system as you write it, which is something you never want to be doing.

There are a lot of solutions for this that provide a better, more reliable systems then anything you can make yourself, but I can understand the educational value of this sort of project. I made my own 'auto-update/launcher' recently for just that reason, and it works reasonably well, albeit on a free webserver with myself an some friends as the only users.

Here's the flowchart I made for it:

[image]
Large:https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJaL8.png

This is actually the second iteration of my little project, with the first being less then overwhelming and somewhat disastrous in uncommon circumstances, but it's a good learning experiance. This one also has goofy command files that I can define things like showing messages to the user during an update, which is nice.

If you don't mind looking at terrible and messy code, you can look through the [code repo here](https://bitbucket.org/BrokenPixels/bp_root.xalron), although it's not documented and a few part's aren't actually used but haven't been removed from source control. An example application that uses it is [here](http://brokenpixels.tk/programs/bptalk.html) ([source, also messy](https://bitbucket.org/BrokenPixels/bptalk)).

Sorry for what looks like a shameless self-plug, but I can't really answer your question directly and hope that you might be able to make use of some of this as an indication of how you should go about doing this, since it's actually a pretty fun project.

Comment: +1 for the flowchart and lockfiles. Anyways, does there really not exist such generic-purpose appversion trackers/downloders already? Especially in the .Net, ClickOnce, WebPlatform, app hosting etc, I'm (almost) sure everything is already there..

Comment: Thanks. There are lots of better update systems, like you said. I was looking at the [.Net Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx) originally. However, it actually required a WebDAV server, so being the cheapskate I am, I made my own around the idea it can be hosted off of the most restrictive web server you can get, (even one that doesn't allow hosting of .zip files!) and while I really wouldn't recommend anyone else use it in their apps, it fits my personal needs of sending updates to a handful of lazy friends, completely free, and it was fun. ;)

Comment: Thank you all for the great info. I will keep looking into this. The main reasion I like to make my own is becouse of the list of updates. Most updaters that I have looked at does not seem to download the first update then the next from the list. They seem to go right to the highest update number or the first one only. Problem there is that I do not wont to include all other updates in with newest becouse of file size after a while. Thanks everyone.